# C# sizing picturebox to fit the fullscreen version of the window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I don't want to change the image size. I added this feature after I created my image. I am using the Windows Forms App (.NET framework). I made stuff using the paint feature, with coordinates and stuff. And I now anted to change it so it gets converted so it's in a picturebox to getter better quality on my animations. But I can only size the picturebox to the size of the small window. But I have based everything off of the full sized window. And now I can only see the part of the painting that fits in the small window which is the stuff in the top left. I need the picturebox to be as big as the full size window
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace France
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int cloudone1, cloudone2, cloudone3, cloudtwo1, cloudtwo2, cloudtwo3, cloudthree1, cloudthree2, cloudthree3;
        Bitmap bmp;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cloudone1 = 0;
            cloudone2 = 50;
            cloudone3 = 100;
            cloudtwo1 = 400;
            cloudtwo2 = 450;
            cloudtwo3 = 500;
            cloudthree1 = 800;
            cloudthree2 = 850;
            cloudthree3 = 900;
            bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            Pen BlackP = new Pen(Color.Black, 4);
            PointF[] Triangle = new PointF[4];
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightBlue, 0, 0, 1280, 660);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 0, 500, 1280, 660);
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, 1100, 50, 100, 100); // Sun (middle of sun is 1150, 100)
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, 1075, 100, 1000, 100);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, 1225, 100, 1300, 100);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, 1150, 175, 1150, 250);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, 1150, 25, 1150, 0);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, 1100, 150, 1050, 200);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, 1200, 150, 1250, 200);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, 1100, 50, 1050, 4);
            g.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, 1200, 50, 1250, 4); // Sun rays
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 30, 550, 65, 470); // Eiffel Bottom Left Outer Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 50, 550, 85, 470); // Eiffel Bottom Left Inner Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 70, 459, 85, 409); // Eiffel Middle Left Outer Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 90, 459, 105, 409); // Eiffel Middle Left Inner Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 107, 400, 110, 368); // Eiffel Top Left Inner Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 88, 400, 100, 325); // Eiffel Top (Bottom Half) Left Outer Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 100, 325, 105, 250); // Eiffel Top (Top Half) Left Outer Line

            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 190, 550, 155, 470); // Eiffel Bottom Right Outer Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 170, 550, 135, 470); // Eiffel Bottom Right Inner Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 150, 459, 135, 409); // Eiffel Middle Right Outer Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 130, 459, 115, 409); // Eiffel Middle Right Inner Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 113, 400, 110, 368); // Eiffel Top Right Inner Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 132, 400, 120, 325); // Eiffel Top (Bottom Half) Right OuterLine
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 120, 325, 115, 250); // Eiffel Top (Top Half) Right Outer Line

            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 60, 485, 160, 485); // Eiffel Bottom Horizontal Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 80, 424, 140, 424); // Eiffel Middle Horizontal Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 100, 260, 120, 260); // Eiffel Top (Bottom) Horizontal Line
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 100, 250, 120, 250); // Eiffel Top (Top) Horizontal Line

            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 110, 250, 110, 220); // Eiffel Top Vertical Line

            g.DrawRectangle(BlackP, 27, 550, 23, 15); // Eiffel Bottom Left Base Box
            g.DrawRectangle(BlackP, 170, 550, 23, 15); // Eiffel Bottom Right Base Box
            g.DrawRectangle(BlackP, 60, 459, 100, 11); // Eiffel Bottom/Middle Seperator Box
            g.DrawRectangle(BlackP, 80, 400, 60, 9); // Eiffel Middle/Top Seperator Box

            g.DrawArc(BlackP, 67, 495, 86, 35, 180, 180); // Eiffel Bottom Arch

            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 170, 550, 175, 515); // Bottom Right Crosses
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 175, 515, 142, 485); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 190, 550, 155, 515); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 155, 515, 160, 485); //

            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 50, 550, 45, 515); // Bottom Left Crosses
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 45, 515, 78, 485); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 30, 550, 65, 515); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 65, 515, 60, 485); // ____

            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 70, 459, 95, 440); // Middle Left Crosses
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 95, 440, 80, 425); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 90, 459, 75, 437); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 75, 437, 100, 426); // ____

            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 150, 459, 125, 440); // Middle Right Crosses
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 125, 440, 140, 425); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 130, 459, 145, 440); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 145, 440, 120, 425); // ____

            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 88, 400, 124, 345); // Top crosses
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 132, 400, 96, 345); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 96, 345, 120, 320); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 124, 345, 100, 320); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 100, 320, 118, 295); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 120, 320, 102, 295); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 102, 295, 118, 275); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 118, 295, 102, 275); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 102, 275, 118, 260); //
            g.DrawLine(BlackP, 118, 275, 102, 260); // ____
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, cloudone1, 10, 75, 50); // Cloud one
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, cloudone2, 20, 100, 50); //
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, cloudone3, 5, 100, 50); //  ____
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, cloudtwo1, 55, 75, 50); // Cloud two
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, cloudtwo2, 45, 100, 50); //
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, cloudtwo3, 50, 100, 50); //  ____
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, cloudthree1, 45, 75, 50); // Cloud three
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, cloudthree2, 40, 100, 50); //
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGray, cloudthree3, 35, 100, 50); //  ____

            Triangle[0] = new PointF(1100, 200);
            Triangle[1] = new PointF(1175, 50);
            Triangle[2] = new PointF(1250, 200);
            Triangle[3] = new PointF(1100, 200);
            //g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Purple, Triangle);
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            g.Dispose();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cloudone1 = cloudone1 + 2;
            if (cloudone1 == 1000)
            {
                cloudone1 = 0;
            }
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

to full size on picturebox use this code `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;` , It is better to use this symbol as well, in order to fill the image into the window `pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`
The window must also be none border `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;`
Use them in the following order

1. `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;`
2. `pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`
3. `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`

Comment: Unfortunately all this did is make it automatically fullscreen but still only shows what is in the top left corner. I figure it will help if I just show my code. I used bitmap and stuff because I don't want the animation to flimmer

Comment: As for the continuation of the image in motion, it is Timer. If it is running it will keep spinning, if not it will stop (i mean the Timer)

Comment: mate, make sure that you put a correct mark in green under the title Answer there is a check mark make it green, this is with us the question has been answered. if you need more help just go in this server in discord "VSF Hub"

Answer (score 0):

to stop image effect use this

first go to Form_Load and put this code:

- `this.KeyPreview = true;`

after this go to Form Event and double click in `KeyDown` and put this code to stop the moving image

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
      {
          if(timer1.Enable == true)
          {
              timer1.Enabled = false;
              return;
          }
          if(timer1.Enable == false)
          {
              timer1.Enabled = true;
              return;
          }
      }
}
```

if you press Space will stop the timer, and stop the image

if you want to stop the image like automatically use this

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cloudone1 = cloudone1 + 2;
            if (cloudone1 == 1000)
            {
                timer1.Enable = false;
            }
            Invalidate();
        }
```